# Explanation of make directives

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working with an existing makefile and it has some content I am unfamiliar with:

```
# SOURCE statements are to tell Make where to find the file types:
.SOURCE.c : $(SOURCEPATH)                   #  .c files location
.SOURCE.s : $(SOURCEPATH)                    #  .s files location
.SOURCE.h : $(HDRLIST)                      #  .h files location (all)
.SOURCE.o : $(OBJPATH)  $(ROMOBJPATH)        #  .obj files location
###########################################################################
```

This is the only place in the makefile that 'SOURCE' is used.  The $(...PATH) variables are set to the associated directories with the exception of $(HDRLIST) with is a space delimited list of directories

I believe the make is a variety of GNU make but I don't see this syntax described in the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf).

Has anyone else seen this format and can point me to a document describing it?

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found that the make being used is part of the MKS Toolkit.  This make includes some [additional directives](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/make.1.asp#Special_Target_Directives) that include the .SOURCE directive.

> .SOURCE  The prerequisite list of this target defines a set of
>   directories to check when trying to locate a target file name.
>
> .SOURCE.x  Same as .SOURCE, except that make searches the .SOURCE.x
>   list first when trying to locate a file matching a target with a name
>   that ends in the suffix .x.